# Sharp animation on IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I made animation on click, and it looks fine on PC. The problem is that animation on Android and iOS is sharp and looks ragged. I searched for solution for a long time, but still haven't find any solution.

This is my JS, you can view all the code on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/146zatgp/16/).

```
$('.project-image').on('click', function() {
var $this = $(this);
var img = $(this).attr('id');
var minusLeft = $(this)[0].offsetLeft - 8;
var minusTop = $(this)[0].offsetTop - 80;

$('.show-description').fadeOut(600, function () {
    $('.hide-description').fadeIn(600);
});

$('.flex-container img').not('#' + img).animate({
    opacity: 0,
}, 200, "linear", function() {
  $this.css({
    top:'-'+minusTop+'px',
    left:'-'+minusLeft+'px'
    })

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.flex-container img').not('#'+img).hide();
        $this.css("position", 'static');
        $('.flex-container').css('flex-flow', 'column wrap');

        $('.'+img+'-text-block').show();
        $('.'+img+'-text-block').animate({
            opacity:1
          }, 100)
    }, 600)
});

})

$('.hide-description').on('click', function() {

$('.hide-description').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('.show-description').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('[class*="-text-block"]').hide()
$('.flex-container').css('flex-flow', 'row wrap')
$('.flex-container img').css({
    position: 'relative',
    top:0,
    left:0
})
$('[class*="-text-block"]').css('opacity', '0');
$('.flex-container img').animate({
    opacity: 1,
}, 400)
$('.flex-container img').show()

})
```